"Object Required" Object or Range Reference for vba With For loop
I'm using vba to evaluate 2 columns and either populate text, or color change based on comparison between 2 dates. Seems like this should be easy.
I'm not super proficient in VBA, so I'm struggling with knowing when to use (range reference).Value.
I'm getting Error 424 Object Required. highlighting the
Set = Actual portion of the code.
Any assistance from more experienced coders would be appreciated!
Sub ColorTATCol()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Plate Analysis")

 With ws

 Dim LR As Long
 LR = Sheet1.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

  Dim i As Long
  Dim Actual As Date
  Dim Projected As Date

    For i = 3 To LR

     Set Actual = Cells(i, "P").Value
     Set Projected = Cells(i, "O").Value
     
     'If ActualTAT row is empty, ActualTAT = "not complete"
     'If ProjectedTAT row is empty, ProjectedTAT = "no receipt date"
     If IsEmpty(Actual.Value) = True Then
     Actual.Value = "not complete"
     If IsEmpty(Projected.Value) = True Then
     Projected.Value = "no receipt date"
     End If
    End If
    'if ActualTAT is a Date And <= Projected TAT, interior color index = 8 (blue)
    If IsDate(Actual.Value) = True And Actual.Value <= Projected.Value Then
    Actual.Value.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
      'if ActualTAT > Projected TAT, interior color index = 4 (green)
      Else
      Actual.Value.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
      End If
    Next i
 End With
End Sub```


Set is only used for object-type variables.  Actual = Sheet1.Cells(i, "P").Value

Thank you, I modified my code. I'm getting a new error of "Invalid Qualifier" for Actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 8 regardless of whether I include .Value or not.

If Actual is a Date then it doesn't have an Interior.  Did you mean to declare Actual as a Range?

Are "Plate Analysis" and Sheet1 the same worksheet?

Ah, I should declare it as a Range.
And yes, Plate Analysis is Sheet1

More like this maybe:
Sub ColorTATCol()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, ci As Long
    Dim Actual As Range, Projected As Range '## not as Date
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Plate Analysis")
    
    LR = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    
    For i = 3 To LR
    
        Set Actual = ws.Cells(i, "P")
        Set Projected = ws.Cells(i, "O")
    
        'If ActualTAT row is empty, ActualTAT = "not complete"
        'If ProjectedTAT row is empty, ProjectedTAT = "no receipt date"
        If IsEmpty(Actual.Value) Then Actual.Value = "not complete"
        If IsEmpty(Projected.Value) Then Projected.Value = "no receipt date"
        
        'if ActualTAT is a Date And <= Projected TAT, interior color index = 8 (blue)
        If IsDate(Actual.Value) And Actual.Value <= Projected.Value Then
            Actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        'if ActualTAT > Projected TAT, interior color index = 4 (green)
        Else
            Actual.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub


This did get rid of my errors!
However, I don't think my IsDate is doing anything, as "not complete" still gets colored in, and dates without a projected TAT are colored in too. That is the least of my concerns though, and shouldn't be too difficult to fix

IsDate("not complete") is False for me...
